# Editing SVG styles from javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, styles

I have an SVG map of the world, and I want to colour each region by various metrics in real time by altering style attributes for each region in the svg. For example, I want to tint the UK blue.

This needs to be dynamic as the data changes often and is pushed out to the browser.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can apply CSS styling to SVG Elements. Needless to say, this requires a suitable markup. So for instance, if your map looks something like (VERY simplified :-)

```
<svg>
    <g id="USA">...</g>
    <g id="UK">...</g>
</svg>
```

You could simply do the following:

```
var country = document.getElementById("UK");
country.setAttribute("style", "fill: blue; stroke: black");
```

Of course it is also possible to embed stylesheets into an SVG document:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      <![CDATA[
      // insert CSS rules here
      ]]>
    </style>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

And finally, it is also possible to include an external stylesheet into an SVG document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css"?>
<svg>
    ...
```

Comment: Is there any way to change style under defs using js

Answer (score 7):

I case you don't want to change the whole style, you can do:

```
var country = document.getElementById("UK");
country.style.fill = "blue";
country.style.stroke = "black";
```

Comment: Info provided in this answer is same as the above answer. Just repeated and wrote answer below

Comment: @SandeepChikhale No, it's a useful distinction from the other answer. Sometimes you don't want to update the whole style but just one attribute.